# Using profile with selenium closes current browser window with different profile

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, brave

I am trying to run selenium using profile. I know that if a profile is already opened normally on a browser, opening the same via selenium will be erroneous. So I made a second profile and am trying to open it (via selenium) while running the first profile in a normal browser window.

But the problem is that running the code first closes the current browser window and then opens the second profile.

Here is the code

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from time import sleep

options = Options()
options.binary_location = '/snap/brave/current/opt/brave.com/brave/brave'
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=/home/dhruv/snap/brave/current/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/")
options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Profile 1")
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

try :
    print("Driver created")
    print("Sleeping")
    sleep(50)
    driver.get("brave://settings/appearance")
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file("screenshot1.png")
finally :
    driver.close()
```

I am using brave browser with chromium version `116.0.5845.180`, chromedriver version `116.0.5845.96` and selenium version `4.11.2`.

Here is a [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YpjGljx-5dKN_Rtst5sSrOePHx4Q6wwu/view?usp=sharing). Notice how the first browser closes at 0:02.